# como hacer un slider dinamico de videos e imagenes con javascript y php

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un slider que muestra videos e imágenes y quisiera que al tener videos, estos se reproduzcan continuamente y luego mostrar imágenes en el caso de que existan.

Hasta ahora logro mostrar videos e imágenes en un lapso de 5 segundos lo que no me sirve del todo, por ende, ¿como puedo hacer que al terminar el primero video, reproduzca el siguiente y así sucesivamente hasta que no existan más videos y continúe con las imágenes que se irán mostrando cada 5 segundos?

HTML/PHP:

```
<main class="main">
    <div class="slideshow">
        <ul class="slider">
        <?php while($not = $noticias->fetchObject()): ?>
        <?php if($not->tipoNoticia == 'video'): ?>
            <li>
                <video autoplay muted id="video1" class="video-slide">
                    <source src="uploads/videos/<?=$not->nombre?>" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($not->tipoNoticia == 'imagen'): ?>
            <li>
                <img class="imagen-slide" src="uploads/images/<?=$not->nombre?>" alt="">
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</main>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var imgItems = $('.slider li').length; // NUMERO DE SLIDES
var imgPos = 1;

setInterval(function(){
    nextSlider();
}, 5000);

function nextSlider(){
    if(imgPos >= imgItems){
        imgPos = 1;
    }else{
        imgPos++;
    }

    $('.slider li').hide(); // OCULTAMOS TODOS LOS SLIDES
    $('.slider li:nth-child('+ imgPos +')').fadeIn(1000); // MOSTRAMOS SLIDE SELECCIONADO

}
```

});

Gracias por sus respuestas :D